# Docker Compose - restrict service access to some container and disable access from outside docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have four services `service1, service2, service3, postgres`. Each one is exposed via some port. What I want is that `postgres` service should only be accessible from docker containers and not from VM via `psql` command (disabling access from outside docker).

Here is my docker-compose.local.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: registry.domain.com/postgres-multi:9.5
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      LC_ALL: C.UTF-8
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES: service1,service2,service3
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  service1:
    container_name: service1
    build:
      context: ./service1
      args:
        environ: local
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://postgres/service1'
      DJANGO_MANAGEPY_MIGRATE: 'on'
      DJANGO_MANAGEPY_COLLECTSTATIC: 'on'
      DJANGO_LOADDATA: 'off'
      DOMAIN: '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - ./service1/app:/home/service1/app/app

  service2:
    container_name: service2
    build:
      context: ./service2
      args:
        environ: local
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8002:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - service1
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://postgres/service2'
      DJANGO_MANAGEPY_MIGRATE: 'on'
      DJANGO_MANAGEPY_COLLECTSTATIC: 'on'
      DJANGO_LOADDATA: 'on'
      DOMAIN: '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - ./service2/app:/home/service2/app/app

  service3:
    container_name: service3
    build:
      context: ./service3
      args:
        environ: local
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8003:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - service1
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://postgres/service3'
      DJANGO_MANAGEPY_MIGRATE: 'on'
      DJANGO_MANAGEPY_COLLECTSTATIC: 'on'
      DJANGO_LOADDATA: 'on'
      DOMAIN: '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - ./service3/app:/home/service3/app/app

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: Please specify reason for down-vote ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to expose Postgres, I suggest removing your port mapping: `ports: - "5432:5432"`. That is mapping the host port 5432 to the container port, which makes it available externally from that port on your host.

Comment: Would my other container services still be able to connect to it ?

Comment: Yes -- the container will automatically listen on port 5432. What you're doing is the extra step of mapping the host port to that port, but that's not necessary if you just want containers to connect to it. Containers can reference it by DNS name at `postgres:5432`